# how to open google play store from browser in android

Tags: android, google-play

I have the Android application, from that I share one post to my friend using WhatsApp, so my friend receives link to that post and link is generated by the server. So when my friend clicks on that link, I want to check if the app is installed then that post get opened in application otherwise it open google play store app in the mobile with my application page. So help me with this, guide me.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: if you are sharing from WhatsApp and other social media then you have to use invite referral program, By using firebase it is not possible to send the deep link via Whatsapp, it supports on Gmail and messaging service. Invite reffreal will help you to find which user has installed app or not.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is implemented using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)